SLF4j is not working with log4j in Spring application when we have logj.xml in external folder
I have slf4j-api, slf4j-log4j12(2.0.7) and  log4j(1.2.17)dependencies in my pom.xml along with spring 5.3.18 and sample code also in applicationcontext.xml I have below configuration which is working fine with log4j LogManager but with SLF4j LoggerFactory it does not work`
<bean id="log4jConfigurer"               class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="configure" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
                 <value>${logging.config}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean> 

I tried adding path log4j.xml  to env variable like
-Dlogging.config=\path\code\properties\log4j.xml with this(apache log4j)
 private static final Logger _logger = LogManager.getLogger(UserController.class);

I am able to see the logs as per configuration available in log4j.xml but whenever I am using SLF4j LoggerFactory
private static final Logger _logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

my external configuration is not picked up.
